# Ошибка в Google Chrome, связанная с websocket

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket, firefox

Такие дела: есть сервер, к которому клиент подключается по адресу

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://94.154.82.166:8000/connection/websocket");
```

В Firefox, после изменений в about:config все нормально - подключение проходит, все работает.
В Google Chrome возникает следующая ошибка:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS..

В других браузерах как дела не знаю. Возможности получить и установить SSL сертификат нет. Какие есть варианты?

Comment: WebSocket сервер находится на том же сервере, что и страница? Страница отдается по https? Где вы взяли для нее сертификат?

Comment: можно на nginx-е "своего" сервера для настроить проксирование на 94.154.82.166:8000. будет норм